# Harmonic accuracy check

Tags: harmony, chord-progressions, composition, functional-harmony

I would like a harmonic accuracy check for a variation that I composed based on a section of the first movement of Brahms's Violin Concerto. I am concerned with whether or not the notes of Bars 18 - 22 and Bars 26, 28 are missing required accidentals according the chord progression in the original that those bars are based on. I am asking this question because I have never taken any music theory course or any music composition course, so I don't know whether the harmony of my composed variation is accurate or not. [image: composed passage] [image: Brahms's original]

Comment: This isn't really what we do here.

Comment: Welcome! You can read more about [the topics covered here](https://music.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic); it seems to me that the main problem here is simply that the question is too open-ended; it's nice that it is focused on a very specific chunk and that you show the original. You could edit with a more focused question and have it reopened. But meanwhile, no, I don't see any problems.